# Helpers for UI.dynamic templates in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

In Meteor v0.8.2, it appears that helpers must be created for the individual templates (`Template.story_en`, `Template.story_ne`) called by the dynamic template.

Is it possible to create helpers for just the dynamic template (`Template.story`) and avoid repeating it for all possible templates that the dynamic templates can use, such as in the example below? It appears that the method I'm using requires a lot of repeated code.

**story.html**

```
<template name="story">
    {{> UI.dynamic template=storyTemplate}}
</template>
```

**story.js**

```
Template.story.storyTemplate = function() {
    return "story_" + Session.get('lang')
}


// This does not work
Template.story.color = function() {
    return '#f00'
}


// This works
Template.story_en.color = function() {
    return '#f00'
}

// This works (but seems to be unnecessary code)
Template.story_ne.color = function() {
    return '#f00'
}
```

Comment: is using `UI.registerHelper` not an option?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Ah I have not seen that before... is there an example? Was hoping to make as little changes as possible to the existing template code

Answer (score 1):

You could use global helpers, or pass the helpers in as data

Using Global Helpers (work on every template you have)

```
UI.registerHelper("color", function() {
    return '#f00'
});
```

Or Passing in the helpers as data (does not work under current version of iron router - [open bug](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/691)).

```
Template.story.helpers({
    dataHelpers: function() {
        var data = UI._templateInstance().data || {};

        //Add the helpers onto the existing data (if any)
        _(data).extend({
            color: function() {
                return "#f00";
            }
        });

        return data;

    });
});
```

Then the html:

```
<template name="story">
    {{> UI.dynamic template=storyTemplate data=dataHelpers}}
</template>
```

Then in the subtemplates you can use `{{color}}` without having the helpers in them.

You could also try your luck with using `this` instead of `UI._remplateInstance.data` if you have iron-router issues.